# How to count the number of entries in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counting, database-table

I have a simple Excel sheet, containing different columns, each of them having their title. Each of the cells, containing the title, have a name, e.g. the column containing the first entries (key values), starts with the cell with the name `Header_Title`.

In order to know the amount of entries, which is filled in, I had a very simple idea: lets count the number until the end of the table, so I ended up with something like:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(Header_Title;1;0):...) // I've forgotten how I did it.
```

However, At one moment I've removed some tuples, and now my formula looks like:

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(Header_Title;1;0):#REF!)
```

How can I say:
`Continue to the end of the column but if any tuples get deleted, don't change this formula`?

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a "normal" Table? and a formula like:

```
=AGGREGATE(2;4;Table1[Header_Title])
```

or:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103;Table1[Header_Title])
```

Comment: The issue is, how to find the end of the table? `Header_Title` is just one cell, containing the title of the column. I need to know how to define the table, e.g. `Table[Header_Title:...]` (what to put in the three dots?).

Comment: This is a possibility: =COUNTA(INDEX(1:1048576;;COLUMN(Header_Title)))-ROW(Header_Title) When below your "table" all cells are blank

Comment: But when using real Tables  (insert Table eg Ctrl-T) there's no need for complicated formulas

Comment: But that is just one of the powers of Tables, they will grow dynamically